# Responsive CSS Topnav with dropdown not working on samll screens

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropdown, responsive

I am trying to learn how to make a responsive CCS page and is following a tutorial on W3schools (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_responsive_navbar_dropdown.asp)

I have coded my version and all works good on Desktop size, however when I try to go to Iphone5/Iphone6/Ipad sizes the menu dont show after clicking on the button with the javascript.

I am stuck and have tried my best to find  out why it wont work as the one on  the tutorial - can somebody help/guide me to what that needs to change for?

My html looks like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <title>My page</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One|Noto+Sans:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../style/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- topp logo start -->
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="../bilder/logo.gif" alt="Logo">
        <p>Some header text</p>
    </div><!-- topp logo slutt --><!-- Menu start -->
    <div>
        <nav>
            <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
                <a class="active" href="/Test.htm">Startpage</a>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">Group1 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#" target="_parent">Option1</a>
                        <a href="#" target="_parent">Option1</a>
                        <a href="#" target="_parent">Option1</a>
                        <a href="#" target="_parent">Option1</a>
                        <a href="#" target="_parent">Option1</a>
                        <a href="#" target="_parent">Option1</a>
                        <a href="#" target="_parent">Option1</a>
                        <a href="#" target="_parent">Option1</a>
                        <a href="#" target="_parent">Option1</a>
                        <a href="#" target="_parent">Option1</a>
                        <a href="#" target="_parent">Option1</a>
                        <a href="#" target="_parent">Option1</a>
                        <a href="#" target="_parent">Option1</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">Group2 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#" target="_parent">Option1</a>
                        <a href="#" target="_parent">Option1</a>
                        <a href="#" target="_parent">Option1</a>
                        <a href="#" target="_parent">Option1</a>
                        <a href="#" target="_parent">Option1</a>
                        <a href="#" target="_parent">Option1</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">Group3 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#" target="_parent">Option1</a>
                        <a href="#" target="_parent">Option1</a>
                        <a href="#" target="_parent">Option1</a>
                        <a href="#" target="_parent">Option1</a>
                    </div>
                </div><a class="icon" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()" style="font-size:15px;">&#9776;</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");   
    if (x.className === "topnav") {      x.className += " responsive";    } 
    else {      x.className = "topnav";    } }  
    </script>
    <!-- menu end -->
    <div class="sesbanner">
        <picture>
        <source media='(min-width: 401px)' srcset='sesbanner/big.jpg'>
        <source media='(max-width: 400px)' srcset='sesbanner/tall.jpg'>
        <img src='sesbanner/small.jpg'></picture>
        <div class="sestext">
            SUBJECT<br>
            2019
        </div>
        <div class="sesliten">
            Choose option from above menu.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="adressbar">
        <h3>Company</h3><br>
        <br>
        Adr1<br>
        Adr2<br>
        ZIP City<br>
        <br>
        Phone: +11 11 11 11<br>
        Fax:   +22 22 22 22<br>
        <br>
        <a href="mailto:post@site.com">Email: post@site.com</a><br>
    </div><!-- Footer -->
    <div class="footer">
        &#169;All rights reserved 2019.
        <center>
            <table id="footertabell">
                <tr>
                    <td>Made by me</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </center>Some text.<br>
        Some more text.
    </div><!-- END -->
</body>
</html>
```

and the css style file like this:

```
h1{
  font-size: 2.25em;
   line-height: 2.25em;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
h2{
  font-size: 1.875em;
   line-height: 2em;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
}

h3{
  font-size: 1.25em;
   line-height: 1.375em;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
}
h4{
  font-size: 1em;
   line-height: 1.125em;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
}
h5{
  font-size: 0.875em;
   line-height: 1em;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
}
h6{
  font-size: 0.75em;
   line-height: 0.875em;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
}
.paragraph {
  font-size: 0.875em;
  line-height: 1em;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
}
.medium {
  font-size: 0.875em;
  line-height: 1em;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
text-align: center;
color: darkgray;
}

.liten {
  font-size: 0.5625em;
   line-height: 0.625em;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
}
p.bold {
  font-weight: 600;
}


.logo {

    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    font-family:'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
    font-size: 2.00em;
    color: white;
}


.vgrtema{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: space-evenly;
 align-items: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;



  background-color: #e7e7e7;

}

.vgrtema.img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;

}
.vgrtextheader {


font-family:'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
font-size: 1.75em;
color: black;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 1.5em;
}



.sesbanner {
position: relative;
text-align: center;
color: white;
background-color: black;
}


.sestext {
 font-family:'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
font-size: 3em;
text-transform: uppercase;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

.sesliten {
font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
font-size: 1em;
text-transform: uppercase;
position: absolute;
top: 85%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

/*Menu start */

nav {margin:0;
  font-family:'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
  font-size: 1.00em;
 background-color: black;
}
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: darkgray;
}
/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.active {
  background-color: darkgray;
  color: white;
}
/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}
/* Dropdown container - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
/* Style the dropdown button to fit inside the topnav */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}
/* Style the dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
/* Style the links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
/* Add a dark background on topnav links and the dropdown button on hover */
.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}
/* Add a grey background to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
/* Show the dropdown menu when the user moves the mouse over the dropdown button */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one 
("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}


/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. 
This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

/*Menu end  */
```

Comment: Can you put this into a jsfiddle or a codepen so we can better see the problem?

Comment: Hi you can fin a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mikkmakk/5zL0byd2/2/